# Azure Cosmos what happens if partition key value is null

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In Azure Cosmos I have selected partition key as City. But it is possible that this key can have a null also. In such a case. Will all the City with null be in one partition.

How will the partition be distributed in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain there is a hidden partition and all the documents without a partition key would go to that partition.

I recall reading this somewhere on SO answers\comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can create. Null, Undefined, and empty string are treated as different values in Cosmos DB.

```
new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(null) }
```

As **`4c74356b41`** mentioned There will be a separate partition and these values will go under that.